# cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); max() not recognize it

Tags: c++

I'm taking an intro to C++, and I'm using VStudio 2013 on Win7. I try to avoid the wrong data input from my menus, and it's working in all of them except this one.

```
    cout << "Please choose your second number" << endl;
    cin >> move2;

    if (move2 < 1 || move2 > size)
    {
        cout << "That's not a valid move" << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        cin.sync();
        cin.clear();
    }
```

the only difference is that in the condition for move > a variable (size) not a number. When I enter a char it goes back to the question asking for another input, but if I enter a word, it breaks!

I try to use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` but the compiler highlights `max()` and it says "expecting identifier".

It maybe easy for all of you good programmers, but I don't know how to fix it. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 24):

This is because in Visual Studio when you use the windows includes it will define a macro max(). If you hover over the max() in your example you should receive an intellisense warning. You can solve this problem by undefining max after all your includes and before any code.

```
#undef max
```

Answer (score 10):

To use `std::numeric_limits<T>` you'll need to include `<limits>`. Further, the type passed to it need to be known *and* actually the type `std::streamsize`, i.e., I would use it as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
// ...
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Also, you should probably make sure that your attempt to read something was actually successful and, if it was not, first `clear()` the stream's state. Here is a complete program (it certainly compiles and runs with [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int move2, size(3);
    while (!(std::cin >> move2) || move2 < 1 || size < move2) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "invalid input ignored; please enter a valid move\n";
    }
    std::cout << "move2=" << move2 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Dietmar. I try to do it like this and I included <limits> , but now streamsize is highlighted and it says... type name is not allowed. Am I missing another library??

Comment: @user3078454: sorry, I had typed this stuff on a mobile device and the second version used an entirely wrong expression. I just edited the answer to fix it.

Comment: Maybe I should add the whole function

Answer (score 1):

**Code that Limits Potential Side Effects**

In my testing, `#undef max` does not seem to need to be done before any `#include`s.

You might want to limit potential side effects in general by first pushing the `max` macro, then undefining it, then popping it off after using max from `<limits.h>` like this (only tested on Windows/Visual Studio 2019):

```
  // stuff ...

#pragma push_macro("max")
#undef max
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
#pragma pop_macro("max")

  // more stuff ...
```

See the Microsoft Docs: [push_macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/push-macro?view=vs-2019) and [pop_macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pop-macro?view=vs-2019)

Put it in a function to make it DRY:

```
void CinIgnore() {

#pragma push_macro("max")
#undef max
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
#pragma pop_macro("max")

}
```

Add `std::cin.clear` to make a `CinReset` function:

```
void CinReset() {

  std::cin.clear();

#pragma push_macro("max")
#undef max
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
#pragma pop_macro("max")

}
```

Additional information: this [cppreference.com article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) on `ignore`has a good example of how to use `clear` and `ignore`, along with state flags, effectively, but does not have the necessary fix for Windows/Visual Studio noted above.

**NOTE**: The above, though standard, does not work well with the user interactively inputting EOF (`ctrl-z` - Windows using Visual Studio). I have written a `IStreamUtils` class that includes a Reset method that is more robust. I will add a link to an article about that here later.

Comment: I encountered same problem as OP & only this would compile, as I was already using max() function.

Answer (score -1):

If cin has an error the following will clear the error state and then read in the rest of the line.

```
if(!cin)
{
   cin.clear();
   string junk;
   getline(cin, junk);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and is not working. It works only with number out of range but not with strings

Answer (score -2):

Include:

```
#include <climits>
```

and see if that helps. I had the same issue and when I changed it from limits to climits it was resolved.

Comment: OP needed `<limits>`, not `<climits>`. And Dietmar Kühl already said that in his answer...

Comment: I had the same exact problem and limits did nothing. Climits fixed it.

Comment: That's weird. 1. `numeric_limits` is from `<limits>`. 2. Are you sure you had the *exactly* same problem? Because the fix for OP's one seems to be `#undef max`.

Comment: Yeah. I used that line of code with only <climits> and it worked? Maybe it's because I use Geany.. That would also be strange but i don't know why else mine didn't need <limits>