# getline(cin) behaving unexpectedly (c++)

Tags: c++, getline

I have the following function:

```
void playersetup(string &name){
    char verify;  
    cout<<"Enter player name: ";
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<endl<<"Your name is: " + name + ", is that correct? (Y for yes, any other key for no): ";
    cin>>verify;
    if ((verify=='y')||(verify=='Y')) {
        verify=='n';
    } else {
        playersetup (name);
    }
}
```

It asks for the player's name, asks the user to verify thats the name they intended, if not it calls itself to start over. However this is what the output looks like:

Enter Player Name:

user enters: John Smith

Your name is: John Smith, is that correct? (Y for yes, any other key for no):

user enters: n

Enter Player Name:

(user is not given a chance to input anything)

Your name is: , is that correct? (Y for yes, any other key for no):

Is there logic error here or an aspect of getline(cin) that Im missing?

Comment: You have a huge risk of SO in your code...

Comment: The problem is `cin >> verify` didn't read the newline character. So next time you do `getline`, you get an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newline character remains in standard input as the `>> char` consumes the users single character response only. When `std::getline()` is next invoked it reads the newline character; a blank line. Consume, or skip, the newline character before asking the user for the name again:

```
#include <limits> // for 'std::numeric_limits'

std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

Comment: This did it after a moment of googling, for anyone reading this later hmjd's answer fixed my problem, but I was unaware I had to #include <limits> which I discovered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446373/cin-ignorenumeric-limitsstreamsizemax-n-max-not-rrecognize-it

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `std::getline` after `std::cin >> verify`  you need to flush the newline `'\n'` out of the buffer in between. Otherwise getline reads `'\n'` and returns. You can add a call to `std::basic_istream::ignore` to ignore `'\n'`:

```
#include <limits>

cin>>verify;
cin.ignore ( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

[basic_istream/ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)