# Empty input variable that failed C++

Tags: c++

I've found many posts saying I should be using the following code to empty the input variable in order to reset it:

```
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

But what am I missing here since it's not compiling, it says expected an identifier when mouse hover over max();

code:

```
int Menu::getInput()
{
  int choice;

cin >> choice;

if (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return choice = 3;
}


return choice;
```

}

Comment: Did you include <limits> and have `using namespace std;` at the top of your file?

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes i did.

Comment: If you are using Visual studio then according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21959303/2878796) you might have to undefine the `max` macro first.

Comment: Your [example](https://ideone.com/4K5pJU) works on ideone.com...

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes I am using Visual studio and undefine max solved the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggestions that you've read to use `ignore()` are just band-aids designed to workaround broken logic that attempts to read newline delimited text using `operator>>`.

The general situation goes something like this: "well, I should be reading lines of text that contain two integers, followed by a text string, ok, so I'll use `operator>>` to read two integers, then a `std::string`, from `std::cin`". And that's fine, as long as we all live in a perfect world. Unfortunately, we don't live in a perfect world, and when bad input is encountered, in the middle of this odyssey, we end up with:

- A `std::istream` in an error/fail state.
- An undeterminate amount of consumed input, with a partially read line.

Recovering from this mess is what the using `ignore()` is supposed to achieve, by reading and discarding the remainder of the partially-consumed line, until the next newline characters.

But wouldn't you agree that it's much better not end up in this ugly mess to start with, in the first place?

And that's why if you need to read something that's formatted as lines of text, you should simply use `std::getline()`, to read one line of text at time. What a novel idea!

And then, once you've read the next line of text into a simple, `std::string` buffer, if you feel like it you can go ahead and construct a `std::istringstream` object from it, and use `operator>>` to your heart's content.

And if parsing the line of text, using `std::istringstream`, fails for some reason, you only need to issue an appropriate complaint to the user, then simply loop back, and use `std::getline`() to read the next line of text from your input time, without having to screw around with resetting the stream's status, or discarding partially-processed line. That seems to me like a much simpler, easier approach, doesn't it?

It appears to me that most C++ courses, instructors, and textbooks, are doing a disservice to their students by unceremoniously sprinkling liberal usage of `operator>>`, without properly explaining that this is a completely wrong approach to reading input that's formatted as newline-delimited lines of text. This just leads to nothing but utter confusion, and buggy code.

Take this as an answer to your question: scrap completely what you're doing, and simply rewrite it, simply as:

```
int Menu::getInput()
{
   int choice;
   std::string buffer;

   if (!std::getline(std::cin, buffer).eof())
   {
       std::istringstream i(buffer);

       i >> choice;

       if (!i.fail())
            return choice;
   }

   return 3;
}
```

Money back guarantee: this approach guarantees to never mess up your `std::cin`'s state, or leave it with partially-consumed input.

Comment: Probably the best answer on this topic, I've found so far.

Comment: why not: `... if ( std::getline(std::cin, buffer) ) { ... if ( i >> choice ) return choice;...`? Do you think it's too obscure?